# SSIS - Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page - Special Characters

Tags: ssis

I have a text file with Vertical Bar{|} separated values and I am using a Flat File source to read the values which fails with the above error.

I have a Flat File Connection Manager, where I set the columnwidth of each column. The particular column which causes error has

**DataType - DT_WSTR**

**OutputColumnWidth - 30**

The problem is raised only when the particular column has special characters like 'Société Amomyna da Pramt Hgyme' though it still has only 30 characters.

If I increase the column width it works but I need to know is that the right solution.

Please let me know if you require more details. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you go to the Flat file connection manager under Advanced and Look at the "OutputColumnWidth" description's **ToolTip** It will tell you that **Composit** characters may use more spaces. So the "é" in  "Société" most likely occupies more than one character.

**EDIT**: Here's something about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character

Comment: Thanks, So I increased the "OutputColumnWidth" to 40 from 30 but at during the ADO NET Destination phase it fails with error "The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column" so does this means column width in Database table also has to be increased?

Comment: It might be a problem with your encoding rather than the size. The database NVARCHAR column should handle unicode strings, but you may need to configure your ADO task to handle that.

Comment: Yes I changed the enconding to UTF-8 and all the issues are resolved. I don't even have to increase the OutputColumnWidth. This helped me too "http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html"

Comment: I have increased the width to 5000 whee my string length is just around 100, also chosen UTF-8 while loading the source flat file, still I get this error, pls help me.