# Data export from SQL Server to csv error "data conversion returned status value 4"

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to export data from sql to a csv file using ssis. In the data flow task my source is `OLE DB` and then a data conversion for the column that its failing on set to `data length 500` and in then the `flat file destination`. In the flat file connection settings I made sure the data length is set at `500`.

Still getting the error:

`[Flat File Destination [12]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "description" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".`

NOTE: SSIS set the data length at 450 by recognition and that was the initial fail before I made the change of data length to 500./

Comment: Do a `SELECT MAX(LEN(Description))  FROM TableName` on that column and then set that value to your destination column width. Obviously there are more than 500 characters in your Description column.

Comment: its 450. Thats what I dont understand. It still doesnt work. I tried 900 to take into account if it sees any unique characters even though there shouldnt be any. Any more ideas?

Comment: What's the datatype of the source column in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have some special characters in your data.  Try a different code page in your flat file connection manager.  You can try changing it to 65001 UTF-8

Similar article:

[SSIS - Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page - Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360556/ssis-text-was-truncated-or-one-or-more-characters-had-no-match-in-the-target-c?rq=1)

Comment: in sql it is nvarchar(450) and in destination its DT_WSTR 450

Comment: That sounds right.  Your best bet is to redirect your error rows and look at the description.

Comment: how do I set it to run one row per batch and redirect error rows to sql table?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you cant do that with flat file destination.  What is the encoding on your connection manager, it is usually 1252 by default.  You can try changing it to 65001 UTF-8

Comment: worked! cheers. I should have thought of that but all good now

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there was problem with some special character in data. It worked fine after checking "Unicode" checkbox in Flat file connection manager.

[image]