# SSIS Data Flow from MySQL to SQL Server unicode and non-unicdoe

Tags: mysql, sql-server, unicode, ssis, varchar

I am getting a "`cannot convert between unicode and non-unicdoe string data types`" error in a `Data Flow` task in SSIS and I cannot figure out why.

- I have created an `ADO.NET` connection to a `MySQL DB` using the "`.Net Providers\Odbc Data Provider`" provider using a connection string like so: `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};server=....`
- I have an `OLE DB` connection to a `SQL server`
- I have a `Data Flow` task
- I have an `ADO NET Source` using the `MySQL` connection
- I have an `OLE DB Destination` using the `SQL Server` connection
- all of the columns in the source (`MySQL`) are `varchar(50)`
- all of the columns in the destination (`SQL Server`) are `varchar(50)`

And yet, the `OLE DB Destination` task still errors with '`Column "one" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.`'

I tried to use a `Data Conversion` task to convert everything to "`string [DT_STR]`" and the destination task stopped showing the red X but execution fails with '`Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "one" (13) to column "copy of one" (32). The conversion returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page."`'

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360556/ssis-text-was-truncated-or-one-or-more-characters-had-no-match-in-the-target-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the column length of both `one` and `copy of one`. The length(bits) are not sufficient for the first/second column. increase the length and try. if 40 then change it to >60. Unicode needs more bits to store the string.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much! But I am not sure why Unicode became an issue since the source and destination table are both `varchar(50)`?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan - to help with the "why", please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample of the values in `one` and `copy of one`.

Comment: @RickJames I don't think I'll be able to get that for privacy reasons. I'll have to figure this out internally. Thanks!